# update kendo ui series

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I'm trying to update a series of chart. I have found some methods in `chartOption` but when I change (for example the width) the chart doesn't update.

Is it possible to update the series and if it is how I can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After changing the chart options, you need to call **[redraw()](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#methods-redraw)**.

For example:

```
var chart = $("#chart").data("kendoChart");
chart.options.series[0].width = 4;
chart.redraw();
```

### **[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/Ezuxu)**

In the demo, click the button to change the first series' width.